# How to use array to create a lookup table

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset which contains three columns: station_code, dest_code, fare. Basically, the data inside the station_code and the dest_cde is the same and the fare is the fee required to go specific station.

```
station_code dest_code fare
station1     station1  0
station1     station2  4.6
station1     station3  10
station1     station4  10
station1     station5  12.3
station1     station6  12.3
station1     station7  12.3
station1     station8  12.3
station1     station9  14.7 
station1     station10 14.7
           .
           .
           .
station1     station91 27.5
station2     station1  4.6
station2     station2  0
station2     station3  10
station2     station4  10
station2     station5  12.3
station2     station6  12.3
station2     station7  12.3
station2     station8  12.3
station2     station9  14.7 
station2     station10 14.7
          .
          .
          .
```

till station91

So my question is how can I use the array technique to create a lookup table which is look like that.

```
fee  1    2    3    4   ...
1    0    4.6  10   10
2    4.6  0    10   10
3    10   10   0    4.6
4    10   10   4.6  0
5    12.3 12.3 4.6  4.6
...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

As you can see the index in both the row and column are actually representing the station name, for example row1 = station1, column1 = station1, column2 = station2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take some time to learn the markdown and process.  When posting, help is found by clicking on the question mark in the icon bar.  The best way to update a question with new or missing information is to **edit** the question.  It's ok to answer your own question for posterity.  Data is good. Don't paste pictures of data, paste the actual data in a code block (what's a code block? see help). ** Show effort**, what code you tried and errors met.  Data+Code is best! SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Do the two code variables actually contain 1,2,3,...,91 or do they have actual station codes?  Why do you think this new matrix form will be easier to use than the original format?

Comment: SAS doesn't allow you to access a row/column like that as noted in your matrix notation, so that isn't a great format for storing your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your table like that via a PROC TRANSPOSE, sort your data ahead of time.

```
 proc sort data=have ; 
 by station_code dest_code fare;
 run;

 proc transpose data=have out=want;
 by station_code;
 id dest_code;
 var fare;
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing `fare` as a two-dimensional array.  How you 'load' the array depends on how you plan to use the 'lookup'.

Suppose:

- fares in one data set: `station_code`, `dest_code`, `fare`

  - station code values are literally `station1` … `station91`
- itinerary points in second data set: `personid`, `step_num`, `station_code`
- you want to compute each persons total fare

Example:

```
data totals(keep=personid totalfare);
  * load the station fares into temporary array for use as lookup table;
  array fares(91,91) _temporary_;
  do until (lastfare);
    set fares end=lastfare;
    _from = input(substr(station_code,8),best.);  * parse the number out of code;
    _dest = input(substr(dest_code,8),best.);
    fares(_from,_dest) = fare;
  end;

  * compute each persons total fare;
  do until (endtrips);
    totalfare = 0;
    _from = 0;
    do until (last.personid);
      set trips end=endtrips;
      by personid step_num;

      _dest = input(substr(station_code,8),best.);
      if _from and _dest then totalfare + fares(_from,_dest);
      _from = _dest;
    end;
    output;
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

If the station code values are actually **not** a value from which `1` … `91` can be parsed, an array **can not** be used -- Instead a hash object with a two valued key should be used as your lookup.

```
data totals (keep=personid totalfare);
  * load the station fares into hash for use as lookup table;
  if 0 then set fares; * prep pdv;
  declare fares hash(dataset:'fares');
  fares.defineKey('dest_code', 'station_code'); * reversed keys make it easier to traverse trips;
  fares.defineData('fare');
  fares.defineDone();  * automatically reads dataset:fares and fills hash entries;

  * compute each persons total fare;
  do until (endtrips);
    totalfare = 0;
    dest_code = '';
    do until (last.personid);
      set trips end=endtrips;                  * read in the station for a persons step;
      by personid step_num;

      if fares.find()=0 then do;  * 0 return code means variable fare has the value for the fare from station_code to dest_code;
        totalfare + fare;
      end;

      * prepare for next leg of journey, this is what is meant by easier to traverse;
      dest_code = station_code;
    end;
    output;
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this whole-rounded explanation, I really appreciate that. However, as the beginner in the SAS, I still have some question on your code. 

First of all the station_code is not called as station1 or station2, it is called as NYK, CEN, LAW, it had total 91 station in the dataset.

Here are some question on your coding. 
"if 0 then set fares; * prep pdv;" what is that mean and why should i prepare for the pdv
"do until (endtrips);" what do you mean by the endtrips, it is the station name?
"do until (last.personid);", what is the logic inside this do loop?

Comment: I am so sorry for asking so many questions, i really apppreciate if you can help!!

Comment: There was a typo in both examples, should be `set trips end=endtrips` to set up flag for end on data.  Because the station codes are station names you can't use the first example (array based lookup), you have to use the hash based lookup example.  prepping the pdv means the variables of the data set in the set statement become available to the data step code.   prepping is clean way to get variables ready for use in the hash preparing `defineKey` and `defineData` invocations. The two do untils are nested *DOW* loops that rely on the automatic features of the set and by statement.

Comment: The logic inside the inner most loop is: 1 - read a trip step as the to_place,  2 - check if there is a fare from from_place to to_place, if so accumulate the fare. 3- make the to_place the from_place for the next trip step.  Each trip record read-in overwrites the station_code value from the prior step.